# Vue.js, how to import and use JQuery to initialize a materialize-css carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, materialize

I am trying to use materialize-css with Vue, things are working fine, but there are certain materialize components needs to be initialized using JS or Jquery, Now, I didn't use Jquery before, I installed it using `npm i -s jquery`, but I am a little stuck as to how and where to import and use it. 
the code below is from materialize docs on how to initialize the carousel. hints on how to use it in a .vue component or any alternative way is highly appreciated?

```js
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel');
    var instances = M.Carousel.init(elems, options);
  });

  // Or with jQuery

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.carousel').carousel();
  });
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your component initialize that code in `mounted` hook without using jquery:

```
export default {
     ...
   mounted(){
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel');
        var instances = M.Carousel.init(elems);
      });


    }
```

Comment: I get a reference error, options is not defined for the first part, and for the second, a type error .carousel is not a function, and I think I should use one of them as it says this or that in the comment setting in the middle from the docs.. not really sure what am i missing here !

Comment: @MoSwilam usually i remove the `options` parameter and in the last versions of materialisecss there's no need to jquery, i had updated my answer

Comment: although somethig is still not right, but at least it is showing on the screen now, thanks very much :) .

Comment: two minor issues i guess in the materialize classes or something, items are not swiping automatically, I mean i have to move each item manually, plus the item is not properly centered even though i have the center class in each carousel item. any idea what could i possibly be missing, or maybe you wanna see the code itself ?

Comment: could you post the concerned part of in https://codesandbox.io ? in order to debug it

Comment: Its not getting mounted in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/monjr63vjj), but the same code is working in my local project. thanks